# Why am I getting a "No instance for (Fractional a0) ..." error?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors

The following code doesn't work when I type `test 10`:

```
test m = if m `mod` 2==0
             then m/2
             else m
```

It says the following:

```
No instance for (Fractional a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

It might be some integer or double type problems in `test n` for integer `n`, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Always add type signatures! When GHC knows what type you want some function to be, it can generate much clearer error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `mod` only works for integer types but `/` only works for fractional types, so there's no way to actually use your `test` function.

You can do this instead:

```
test m = if m `mod` 2 == 0
             then m `div` 2
             else m
```

(`div` is integer division.)

Or this:

```
test m | even m    = m `div` 2
       | otherwise = m
```

Or this:

```
test m
    | (d, 0) <- m `divMod` 2 = d
    | otherwise              = m
```